# react router difference between component and render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I really don't get the difference between render and component prop in Route in react router, in docs it says that render doesn't create new element but component does, I tried to go back with history but I found componentWillMount is called when I use render in Route, what do they mean by "if you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component."

Answer (score 101):

[The source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/59a4fbc184f3a3cf4c25ee39a7e97f72efed7849/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L112-L116) tells the difference:

```
if (component)
  return match ? React.createElement(component, props) : null

if (render)
  return match ? render(props) : null
```

When you use `component` prop, the component is instantiated per every call of `Route#render`. It means that, for your component that you pass to `component` prop of Route, constructor, `componentWillMount`, and `componentDidMount` will be executed every time the route is rendered.

For example, if you have

```
<Route path="/:locale/store" component={Store} />
```

and the user navigates to /en/store, then goes elsewhere, and then navigates back to /en/store, the Store component will be mounted, then unmounted, and then mounted again. It is similar to doing

```
<Route path="/:locale/store">
  <Store />
</Route>
```

Compared to that, if you use `render` prop, the component is *evaluated* on every `Route#render`. Remember that every component is a function? This function will be executed as is, without any lifecycle methods. So when you have it like

```
<Route path="/:locale/store" render={Store} />
```

you can think of it as

```
<Route path="/:locale/store">
  {Store()}
</Route>
```

It saves you runtime because no lifecycle methods are run, but it also has a downside in case Store component has some post-mount lifecycle methods like shouldComponentUpdate that may increase performance as well.

---

There was [a good post on Medium about this performance hack](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f), please take a look at it. It's written very well and is applicable to React 16, too.

Comment: In responses to that Medium post, there's [a confirmation that the second option is even faster in react@16](https://medium.com/@trueadm/in-react-16-functional-components-are-quite-a-bit-faster-than-class-components-1afca4931d7c), when compared to stateful components declared as classes.

Comment: thank you very much, i am just confused cause when i use render i find that componentWillMount is called, and if i change the state at some point and go to another route then go back to my component i found the initial state not the changed one, isn't the docs says " updating the existing component not unmounting it"

Comment: {Store()} if this component already has lifecycle methods, if i call it like this, how it  will be executed without any lifecycle methods

Comment: In fact, `render` prop doesn't behave very well with a component declared as class, as well as any class in ES6 isn't callable. See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/wppyEg?editors=1010), open the console and try to navigate links. Class component + render prop will throw an error. Function component + component or render prop does not run lifecycle methods (because there aren't any).

Comment: so can i say that, i use render with function components and component with class components

Comment: I think you could use `component` prop for everything, to be honest, and only switch to `render` prop when it's really necessary. I'd also recommend using some performance analytics tool like Lighthouse to detect which one works best in usage patterns close to the real ones (but please avoid sandboxed perf metrics, these usually fail to detect real bottlenecks).

Comment: so regardless of what method you are using `render` or `component`, if you are rendering a class component it will be mounted and unmounted
 (calling all lifecycle methods) anyway, do I understand it correctly, @RishatMuhametshin?

Comment: Depends on whether you have nested routes and components in them. If you do, navigation within one Route doesn't unmount component if it's put via `component` prop (aka `React.createElement`), but it does unconditionally re-render it if it's put via `render` prop.

Comment: See [a forked Codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/JMMwQL): the message "SmallComponent()" appears per every click on 3rd or 4th link, meaning effectively that the component is being rendered again and again. I actually think React's VirtualDOM engine is smart enough to not update the corresponding part of browser DOM, but not 100% sure.

Comment: One caveat is that if you use `<Route path="/:locale/store" render={Store} />` and you also use react hooks in `Store`, then it's not gonna work because react hooks can only be called in a function component instead of a regular function.

Answer (score 49):

So I'm confused on this section of docs as well, but I finally figure it out.

The key to understand this is the statement "**provide an inline function to the component prop**"

We all know that Route component will re-render when the location changed, and react will compare the old and new virtual DOM tree, get some diff result and apply to the real DOM.

And react will try it's best to reuse the DOM node, unless the **type** or **key** prop of the new ReactElement is changed.

So

```
// 1.
const componentA = React.createElement(App, props)
const componentB = React.createElement(App, props)
console.log(componentA.type === componentB.type)             // true

// 2.
const componentA = React.createElement(() => <App />, props)
const componentB = React.createElement(() => <App />, props)
console.log(componentA.type === componentB.type)             // false
```

All ReactElements created by way 1 have the same type(App component), but they don't have the same type if they are all created by way 2.

Why?

Because there is always a new anonymous function created in the way 2 when the parent component's(The component that contains Route component) render method got invoked, so the **type of new&old ReactElement** is two different instances of the anonymous function

```
() => <App />
```

So in React's point of view, there are different types element and should be treat with **unmount old > mount new** operation, that means every state or changes you made on the old component got loss everytime the parent component re-render.

But why the render prop avoid the unmount and mount behavior? It's an anonymous function too!?

Here I would like to refer the code that @Rishat Muhametshin posted, the core part of Route component's render method:

```
if (component)
  // We already know the differences:
  // React.createElement(component)
  // React.createElement(() => <component/>)
  return match ? React.createElement(component, props) : null

if (render)
  return match ? render(props) : null
```

**render** prop is a function that return a ReactElement when invoked, what's the type of that returned element?

```
<Route render={() => <AppComponent />}></Route>
```

It's AppComponent, not the anonymous function wrapper! Because after jsx compiled:

```
render = () => React.createElement(AppComponent)
render() = React.createElement(AppComponent)

React.createElement(render) =
  React.createElement(() => React.createElement(AppComponent))

React.createElement(render()) =
  React.createElement(React.createElement(AppComponent))
```

So when you use render instead of component prop, the type of element that **render prop** function return will not change on each render, even there always an new anonymous function instance created on each parentElement.render()

On my point of view, you can achieve the same behavior that render prop does with component prop by giving a name to the anonymous function:

```
// Put this line outside render method.
const CreateAppComponent = () => <AppComponent />

// Inside render method
render(){
  return <Route component={CreateAppComponent}/>
}
```

So the conclusion is, there is not performance different between component and render prop if you are use component={AppComponent} directly, if you want to assign some props to AppComponent, use
`render={() => <AppComponent {...props}/> }` instead of `component={() => <AppComponent {...props}/> }`

Comment: Perfect! I think I finally got it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

Most of concepts have been explained by other answers, Let me sort it out by following:

First of all, we have [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/59a4fbc184f3a3cf4c25ee39a7e97f72efed7849/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L112-L116):

```
if (component)
  return match ? React.createElement(component, props) : null

if (render)
  return match ? render(props) : null
```

#### case #1: component without function

```
<Route path="/create" component={CreatePage} />
```

`React.createElement(CreatePage, props)` be called because of `React.createElement(component, props)` from source code. The instantiation would cause to be **remounting**.

#### case #2: render without function

```
<Route path="/create" render={CreatePage} />
```

`React.createElement(CreatePage, props)` **was** called before passing into render prop, and then called by `render(props)` from source code. No instantiation, no remounting.

#### case #3: component with function

```
<Route path="/create" component={ () => <CreatePage /> } />
```

<s>`React.createElement(CreatePage, props)` be called **twice**. First for jsx parsing(anonymous function), First for returning an instance of `CreatePage` from anonymous function, second from source code. So why don't do this in component prop.</s>

Errors point out by [oligofren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200987/oligofren):

> Parsing the JSX does not call it. It just ends up creating the function expression. The reason you don't want to do #3 is that you create a new anonymous type each time, causing re-mounting of the dom.

#### case #4: render with function

```
<Route path="/create" render={ () => <CreatePage /> } />
```

There is an instantiation(jsx parsing) each time when routing to `path=/create`. Does it feel like **case #1**?

### Conclusion

According to the four cases, If we want to **pass prop** to Component, we need to use the **case #4** to prevent remounting.

```
<Route path="/abc" render={()=><TestWidget num="2" someProp={100}/>}/>
```

This is a bit far from the topic, so I leave the [official discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105) for further reading.

Comment: "React.createElement(CreatePage, props) be called twice. " No. It won't. Parsing the JSX does not call it. It just ends up creating the function expression. The reason you don't want to do #3 is that you create a new anonymous type each time, causing re-mounting of the dom.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I wrote bad on that time, the important is the `anonymous` creating once when called, and source code, for total *twice*. Thanks for point out with your downvote, Remind me the error.

Comment: But your answer still says it's called twice, but the anonymous function is not called when you assign it to the `render` prop. It is created once (when you assign it) and it isn't called until the [`render()` method of `Route`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/59a4fbc184f3a3cf4c25ee39a7e97f72efed7849/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L112-L116) calls it. And only _through that call_ is `React.createElement` called, as it is implicitly part of the anonymous function (after JSX parsing).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I haven't used React a period of time, maybe I should just reference your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Even if we don't pass any props to `ComponentToRender`, I found some benefits from using **render** instead of **component**.
By default `<Route \>` pass additional props(`{ history, location, match }`) to `ComponentToRender` when using **component**. We can access this props via **render** callback too, but also we can omit it. 
Why do we need it? Every render of `<Route />'s` parent or any navigation(even if change route to same as before) create new `match` object. 
So when we pass it to our `ComponentToRender`, we will get new props every time, what may cause some performance issues, especially with `PureComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we give a name to a function it would create a new reference when this component would be called from any parent component. That new reference would be passed to the component. But we can avoid the creation of new references by using use callback hook.

```
    // Put this line outside render method.
    const CreateAppComponent = () => <AppComponent />

    // Inside render method
    render(){
      return <Route component={CreateAppComponent}/>
    }
```