# React warning about setState in unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error:

> warning.js:33 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak
>   in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous
>   tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

But I'm not using a componentWillUnMount method.

I'm using a HOC to make sure the user is authenticated before accessing their /account route.

Here's the Route:

```
<StyleRoute props={this.props} path="/account" component= 
{RequireAuth(Account)} />
```

where RequireAuth is the HOC. Here's the HOC:

```
 import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

export default function RequireAuth(Component) {

  return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      this.checkAuth();
    }

    checkAuth() {
      if ( ! this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      }
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.isAuthenticated
        ? <Component { ...this.props } />
        : null;
    }

  }

  return withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

The code works as intended, but I'm getting that error when /account is rendered. As you notice, nowhere in my direct code is there an componentWillUnMount method. I'm really at a loss for why this warning keeps popping up and any info would help.

---

Update 5/23/18:

To get rid of the error and still have props pass down, I did two thing:

1) I opted for a having two higher order functions in parent App component instead of using the HOC. One higher order function is for passing props and the other is to check authentication. I was having trouble passing any props other than the browser history, hence the renderProps function below.

```
renderProps = (Component, props) => {
  return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
}

checkAuth = (Component, props) => {
    if (props.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Component {...props} />
    }
    if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Redirect to='/' />
    }
}
```

2) To use these, I had to user render in my Route, as opposed to component.

```
//I could pass props doing this, sending them through the above functions
<Route exact path="/sitter-dashboard" render={ () => this.checkAuth(SitterDashboard, this.props) } />
<Route exact path={"/account/user"} render={() => this.renderProps(User, this.props)} />

//I couldn't pass props doing this
<Route {...this.props} exact path="/messages" component={Messages} />
```

Here's the documentation on router vs component as a Route render method: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods

Also, here's a good explanation on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render)

Finally, I used this code from the React Router 4 documentation as a template for what I did above. I'm sure the below is cleaner, but I'm still learning and what I did makes a bit more sense to me.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
  fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
       <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Can you try the same by changing ComponentWillMount to ComponentDidMount?

Comment: I did but it throws an error since it needs to know if they are authenticated before the component is rendered.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can remove the history.push from there and set a flag to show that its unauthenticated and return <Redirect path="/"> in render() in unauthenticated cases. The histoty.push will be trying to unmount components which are not mounted hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up using render instead of component, as mentioned in the React Router 4 documentation, and the error went away.

Comment: What do you mean with that? Could you please write a short exemple of your code? I don't find any point of the doc talking about this

Comment: Pibo, done. I still don't know why I was getting the initial error, but it seems to be cleared up now.

Comment: Hi @CameronTharp I believe that I am doing the exact same thing as you, and I do receive the same warning. Here is my take on the routes: https://gist.github.com/ahlusar1989/d46edb1f73987838b358e05649624639. I welcome feedback on if this is a similar pattern as your original implementation. I am particularly wondering why you need render over component props in the route? Is this specific to React Router V4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same error time ago and it was generated by a component which was using ref tag, and there was some manual manipulation.

A good practice to see these kind of errors is drawing your app flow and see when your are calling `setState`.

Another thing I would change if I were you is `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` to check some data. Take into account fb deprecated this functionality.

> This lifecycle was previously named componentWillMount. That name will continue to work until version 17. Use the rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod to automatically update your components.
>
> [Reactjs component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, but I did figure out the reason behind the same, so here is the snippet of code where I was encountering this err.

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

**Cause:**

```
   this.setState({ showLoader: true });
    const { username } = this.state;
    const URL = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
    try {
      const { data } = await axios(URL);
      this.props.apiData(data);
      this.props.history.push("profile");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    this.setState({ showLoader: false });
```

As you can see in the code-snippet, I was doing

```
this.props.history.push("profile");
```

before setting the state.

```
this.setState({ showLoader: false });
```

And then **err** seems to be legit in this case as I was redirecting to a different component and then setting the state on the component I was earlier.

**Solution:**

By placing

```
this.setState({ showLoader: false });
```

above the `this.props.history.push("profile");` solved the problem.

I hope this helps.