# Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am getting this warning every time I sign in,

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.

Here is my code:

authpage.js

```
 handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let { email,password } = this.state
    const data = {
      email : email,
      password : password
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/login',{
      method : 'post',
      body : JSON.stringify(data),
      headers : {
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if(data.success){
        sessionStorage.setItem('userid',data.user.id)
        sessionStorage.setItem('email',data.user.email)
      }
      this.setState({loginData : data,
                     userData : data,
                     email:"",
                     password:""})
      if(data.token) {
        Auth.authenticateUser(data.token)
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
      }
      this.handleLoginMessage()
      this.isUserAuthenticated()
    })
  }

export default withRouter(AuthPage)
```

use `withRouter` so I can access props which I use to navigate `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`
if I didn't use withRouter I cannot access this.props

index.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component : Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render = { props => (
    Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
      <Component {...props} {...rest} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to = {{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
  )
}

const PropsRoute = ({ component : Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render = { props => (
    <Component {...props} {...rest} />
  )}/>
)

const Root = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <PropsRoute exact path = "/" component = { AuthPage } />
      <PrivateRoute path = "/dashboard" component = { DashboardPage } />
      <Route path = "/logout" component = { LogoutFunction } />
      <Route component = { () => <h1> Page Not Found </h1> } />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

I think the problem is with my withRouter, 
how can we access this.props without using withRouter ?

Answer (score 10):

It's async so

```
this.setState({
   loginData : data,
   userData : data,
   email:"",
   password:""
})
```

make error
You can use **this._mount** to check component is mounted or unmount

```
componentDidMount () {
   this._mounted = true
}
componentWillUnmount () {
   this._mounted = false
}
...
if(this._mounted) {
    this.setState({
        loginData : data,
        userData : data,
        email:"",
        password:""
})
...
```

Comment: @tonychen this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029468/react-warning-about-setstate-in-unmounted-component#

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_isMount` with overloading the `setState` function:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMount = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._isMount = true;
}

setState(params) {
    if (this._isMount) {
        super.setState(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems using `this.setState({ any })`.

Every time the component was built, it called a function that used Axios and the response made a `this.setState({ any })`.

My problem was solved as follows:

In the `componentDidMount()` function I call another function called `initialize()` that I left as **async** and through it I can call my function that performs fetch and `this.setState({ any })`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  myFunction = async () => {
      const { data: any } = await AnyApi.fetchAny();
      this.setState({ any });
  }

  initialize = async () => {
    await this.myFunction();
  }
```

Comment: I do not think this will work. There is no where in the code you are evaluating whether the component is mounted or not.

Comment: The problem is to call someone asynchronous by componentDidMount (), I fixed calling another function that is async. But if it still does not solve, I suggest using Redux.

Comment: This may not be entirely solvable by Redux. There is a lengthy thread on Github where people are discussing potential solutions. I don't have the link to it right now but I will post it here when I post it.

Comment: Ok. I'll wait. Thank you!