# Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate)

Tags: react-native

I know this question is asked before but I applied the solutions offered on [Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504195/warning-cant-call-setstate-or-forceupdate-on-an-unmounted-component)

When I run this program in Expo the program starts and gives warning message "Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component ..." [image: First screen I got this warning message] [image: The details of the warning message]but after some time it hangs up. If I build signed apk it takes too much time to install and the application immediately crashes after start up.

The source code of the application is [here](https://github.com/EnginYilmaz/kpbduser/tree/vscode/src) please give me the idea why I am still getting this warning message. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't used React native user flux somehow right way. So that I have made changes to source code that mainly on App.js for the login process. All the changes could be seen as "stackoverflow question - warning-cant-call-setstate-or-forceupdate" commit messages on github for this question.