# ReactJS Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

```
const handleAsyncActions = async () => {
    await this.props.loginSuccess({ login: { data: { ...data } } });
    await localStorage.setItem('oauth', b64EncodeUnicode(JSON.stringify(data)));
    await this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
};
handleAsyncActions();
```

How to solve this problem in best way.

Comment: "To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the `componentWillUnmount` method"...that's how you solve the problem

Comment: `cancel all asynchronous tasks in componentWillUnmount method`. This include clearTimeout, clearInterval, or anything that you use that might update the state.

Comment: I have made asynchronous actions or process into synchronous way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React warning about setState in unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029468/react-warning-about-setstate-in-unmounted-component)