# Testing component with Component.WrappedComponent as an alternative for withRouter shows Warning while running test cases

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test my component 'CBreadcrumb' which uses "withRouter" HOC. While running the test cases, all test cases pass but it shows a warning.

I have already tried checking my code several times. But I am unable to find the cause of the warning.
I also tried looking into these answers but didn't help me.

[Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

[React warning about setState in unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50029468/react-warning-about-setstate-in-unmounted-component)

CBreadcrumb Component

```js
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import Proptypes from 'prop-types';
import Breadcrumb from "react-bootstrap/Breadcrumb";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {TryCatchHandler} from "../../../common-utils";

class CBreadcrumb extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        routes: [],
        currentLocation: ""
    };

    setCurrentLocation = path => {
        this.setState({currentLocation: path});
    };

    setRoutes = routes => {
        this.setState({routes: routes});
    };

    /**
     * GETS ARRAY OF PATH(URL) UPTO CURRENT PAGE
     * @returns {string[]}
     */
    getPathsToInclude = () => {
        let currentLocation = !this.state.currentLocation ?
            this.props.location.pathname : this.state.currentLocation;

        // GET AVAILABLE PATHS IN CURRENT PAGE URL
        let pathsToInclude = ((currentLocation).split('/'));

        // REMOVE THE FIRST EMPTY ELEMENT FROM ARRAY
        pathsToInclude.shift();

        // IF ROUTE IS NOT 'home' ADD 'home' AS FIRST PATH
        pathsToInclude[0] !== "home" && pathsToInclude.unshift("home");

        //INCLUDE '/' IN EACH PATHNAME
        for (let i = 0; i < pathsToInclude.length; i++) {
            i === 0 || i === 1 ? pathsToInclude[i] = "/".concat(pathsToInclude[i])
                : pathsToInclude[i] = pathsToInclude[i - 1] + "/".concat(pathsToInclude[i])

        }

        return pathsToInclude;
    };

    /**
     *
     * @param pathsToInclude
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    addRoutesByPathsToInclude = pathsToInclude => {
        let routes = [];
        pathsToInclude.forEach(value => {
            routes = routes.concat(
                this.props.breadcrumbData
                    .filter(breadCrumb =>
                        breadCrumb.path === value
                    ));
        });
        return routes;
    };

    filterAndSetRoutesUptoCurrentPage = () => {
        this.setRoutes(this.addRoutesByPathsToInclude(this.getPathsToInclude()));
    };

    setCurrentLocationAndFilterRoutes = async path => {
        !path ? await this.setCurrentLocation(this.props.location.pathname)
            : await this.setCurrentLocation(path);
        this.filterAndSetRoutesUptoCurrentPage();
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        TryCatchHandler.genericTryCatch(this.setCurrentLocationAndFilterRoutes());
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        /**
         * SINCE IT IS LIFECYCLE METHOD , IT RUNS WITH EVERY TEST.
         * IN TEST WE DON'T HAVE ACCESS TO 'withRouter' SO IT WILL HAVE TO
         * BE SET MANUALLY IN FEW REQUIRED TEST CASES ONLY.
         * SO FOR OTHER TESTS WHERE THE PROPS ARE NOT SET,
         * 'location' and 'history' OBJECT  WILL NOT BE AVAILABLE RESULTING IN WHOLE TEST SUITE FAILURE.
         */
        if (prevProps.history) {
            const newPath = prevProps.history.location.pathname;
            const oldPath = prevProps.location.pathname;
            if (newPath !== oldPath) {
                TryCatchHandler.genericTryCatch(this.setCurrentLocationAndFilterRoutes(newPath));
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    createBreadcrumbLink = (breadcrumb, index) =>
        index !== this.state.routes.length - 1 ?
            {'href': "#".concat(breadcrumb.path)} : {'active': true};

    getBreadcrumbItemProps = (breadcrumb, index) => {
        const {itemAs, title, target, itemBsPrefix, itemChildren} = this.props;
        return (
            {
                'key': "breadcrumb" + breadcrumb.id,
                'id': "breadcrumbItem" + breadcrumb.id,
                'as': itemAs,
                'title': title,
                'target': target,
                'bsPrefix': itemBsPrefix,
                'children': itemChildren,
                ...this.createBreadcrumbLink(breadcrumb, index)
            }
        );
    };

    getBreadcrumbItems = (breadcrumb, index) =>
        <Breadcrumb.Item
            {...this.getBreadcrumbItemProps(breadcrumb, index)}
        >
            {breadcrumb.name}
        </Breadcrumb.Item>;

    render() {
        const {as, label, listProps, bsPrefix, children} = this.props;
        return (
            <Breadcrumb
                as={as}
                label={label}
                listProps={listProps}
                bsPrefix={bsPrefix}
                children={children}
            >
                {this.state.routes.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
                    this.getBreadcrumbItems(breadcrumb, index)
                ))}
            </Breadcrumb>);
    }
}

React.propTypes = {
    breadcrumbData: Proptypes.array.isRequired,
    as: Proptypes.elementType,
    label: Proptypes.string,
    bsPrefix: Proptypes.string,
    listProps: Proptypes.object,
    children: Proptypes.array,
    title: Proptypes.node,
    target: Proptypes.string,
    href: Proptypes.string,
    active: Proptypes.boolean,
    itemAs: Proptypes.elementType,
    itemBsPrefix: Proptypes.string,
    itemChildren: Proptypes.array
};

/**
 * 'withRouter' IS A HIGHER ORDER COMPONENT PROVIDED BY 'react-router-dom'.
 * 'withRouter' WILL PASS UPDATED 'match', 'location', and 'history' PROPS
 * TO THE WRAPPED COMPONENT WHENEVER IT RENDERS.
 * IN BREADCRUMB COMPONENT IT IS USED TO DETECT THE ROUTE CHANGE ALONG WITH 'componentDidUpdate' LIFECYCLE METHOD.
 */
export default withRouter(CBreadcrumb);
```

CBreadcrumb.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import CBreadcrumb from '../CBreadcrumb';

expect.addSnapshotSerializer(enzymeSerializer);

describe('CBreadcrumb component tests', () => {
    let wrapper, instance;

    const dataForBreadCrumb = [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Home',
            path: '/home'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'General Setup',
            path: '/generalSetup'
        }];

    let setWrapperProps = (cWrapper, propsObject) => {
        cWrapper.setProps(propsObject);
    };

    describe('Breadcrumb Component Tests', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            wrapper = shallow(<CBreadcrumb.WrappedComponent/>);
            setWrapperProps(wrapper, {breadcrumbData: []});
        });

        test('if CBreadcrumb component is defined', () => {
            expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
        });

        test('if renders Breadcrumb component', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('Breadcrumb').length).toEqual(1);
        });

        test('if Breadcrumb component contains all required props', () => {
            let propRequired = [
                'as',
                'label',
                'listProps',
                'bsPrefix',
                'children'
            ];
            let propsAvailableForBreadcrumb = Object.keys(wrapper.find('Breadcrumb').props());
            propRequired.forEach((propAvail, i) => (
                expect(propAvail).toContain(propsAvailableForBreadcrumb[i])
            ));
        });
    });

    describe('CBreadcrumb state tests', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            wrapper = mount(<CBreadcrumb.WrappedComponent/>);
            instance = wrapper.instance();
            setWrapperProps(wrapper, {breadcrumbData: dataForBreadCrumb});
        });

        afterEach(() => {
            wrapper.unmount();
        });

        test('if routes state is defined', () => {
            expect(wrapper.state('routes')).toBeDefined();
        });

        test('if currentLocation state is defined', () => {
            expect(wrapper.state('currentLocation')).toBeDefined();
        });

        test('if state`s property currentLocation is set after componentDidMount', () => {
            setWrapperProps(wrapper, {
                location: {
                    pathname: '/generalSetup'
                },
                history: {
                    location: {
                        pathname: ''
                    }
                }
            });
            jest.spyOn(instance, 'setCurrentLocation');
            instance.componentDidMount();
            expect(instance.setCurrentLocation).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        test('if routes are filtered upto current location and ' +
            'state`s property routes is set after componentDidMount ', async () => {
            // jest.spyOn(instance, 'setRoutes');
            setWrapperProps(wrapper, {location: {pathname: '/generalSetup'}});
            await instance.componentDidMount();
            // wrapper.update();
            expect(wrapper.state('routes').length).not.toBe(0);
        });

        test('if componentDidUpdate lifecycle will be called and ' +
            'routes will be filtered when url changes', async () => {
            await instance.componentDidUpdate({
                location: {
                    pathname: '/generalSetup'
                },
                history: {
                    location: {
                        pathname: '/home'
                    }
                }
            });
            expect(wrapper.state('routes').length).toBe(1);
        });

    });

    describe('BreadcrumbItem Component Tests', () => {

        beforeEach(async () => {
            wrapper = shallow(<CBreadcrumb.WrappedComponent/>);
            instance = wrapper.instance();
            setWrapperProps(wrapper, {
                breadcrumbData: dataForBreadCrumb,
                location: {
                    pathname: '/generalSetup'
                },
            });
            await instance.componentDidMount();
            wrapper.update();
        });

        test('if renders BreadcrumbItem component', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem1').length).toBe(1);
        });

        test('if BreadcrumbItem component shows name', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem1').text()).not.toBe('');
        });

        test('if  BreadcrumbItem components except last has href with value', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem1').prop('href')).not.toBe('');
        });

        test('if last  BreadcrumbItem component  defined', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem2').length).toBe(1);
        });

        test('if last BreadcrumbItem component has no href', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem2').prop('href')).not.toBeDefined();
        });

        test('if last BreadcrumbItem component has prop active', () => {
            expect(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem2').prop('active')).toBeTruthy();
        });

        test('if BreadcrumbItem  component excluding last contains all required props', () => {
            let propRequired = [
                'test-id',
                'as',
                'title',
                'target',
                'bsPrefix',
                'children',
                'href'
            ];

            let propsAvailableForBreadcrumbItem = Object.keys(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem1').props());
            propRequired.forEach((propAvail, i) => (
                expect(propAvail).toContain(propsAvailableForBreadcrumbItem[i])
            ));

        });

        test('if BreadcrumbItem  component including last contains all required props', () => {
            let propRequired = [
                'test-id',
                'as',
                'title',
                'target',
                'bsPrefix',
                'children',
                'active'
            ];

            let propsAvailableForBreadcrumbItem = Object.keys(wrapper.find('#breadcrumbItem2').props());
            propRequired.forEach((propAvail, i) => (
                expect(propAvail).toContain(propsAvailableForBreadcrumbItem[i])
            ));
        });
    });

    describe('Snapshot Testing', () => {
        wrapper = shallow(<CBreadcrumb.WrappedComponent breadcrumbData={dataForBreadCrumb}/>);

        test('if renders CBreadcrumb component correctly', () => {
            expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
    });

});
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {HashRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import CBreadcrumb from "./component/CBreadcrumb/CBreadcrumb";
import AdminSetupPage from "./component/AdminSetupPage/AdminSetupPage";
import {AddPage} from "./component/AdminSetupPage/AddPage";

function App() {
    const dataForBreadCrumb = [
        {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Home',
            path: '/home'
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'General Setup',
            path: '/generalSetup'
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Admin Setup',
            path: '/generalSetup/adminSetup'
        },
        {
            id: '4',
            name: 'Add Admin',
            path: '/generalSetup/adminSetup/add'
        },
        {
            id: '5',
            name: 'Manage Admin',
            path: '/generalSetup/adminSetup/manage'
        },
    ];
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <CBreadcrumb breadcrumbData={dataForBreadCrumb}/>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/generalSetup/adminSetup" component={AdminSetupPage}/>
                <Route path='/generalSetup/adminSetup/add' component={AddPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

It shows warning as shown below

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
        in CBreadcrumb (created by Context.Consumer)
        in withRouter(CBreadcrumb) (created by App)
        in Router (created by HashRouter)
        in HashRouter (created by App)
        in header (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in App
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can refer to [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/). And right towards the end of the article, robinwieruh recommends a possible solution to this problem with `setState()` call and `Component Unmount` issue.

Comment: I also tried following this solution but it didn't work. In my case the warning is being thrown while running test cases @bijayshrestha