# BrowserRouter not working in create-nw-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nwjs

I have created an app using [create-nw-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-nw-react-app). This basically creates a system app which uses reactjs.

So, I have created a route '/' which renders a particular component.

```
<Route 
    exact
    path='/'
    render={() => <Home />}
/>
```

But, the component was not getting rendered. So I have checked the **url** using `window.location.href` and this is the **url** that I have obtained:

```
chrome-extension://dkmbccbbedageiokbcmfaegjedpbegcf/index.html?
```

Is **Routing** even possible with `create-nw-react-app`?

---

> "react-router": "^4.3.1", "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",

```
class Tool extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {window.location.href}
                <Breadcrumb>
                    <BreadcrumbItem><a href='/home'>Home</a></BreadcrumbItem>
                    <BreadcrumbItem><a href='/courses'>Courses</a></BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route 
                            exact
                            path='/home'
                            component={Home}
                        />
                        <Route 
                            exact
                            path='/courses'
                            component={CourseList}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Only the [`Breadcrumb`](http://reactstrap.github.io/components/breadcrumbs/) is getting rendered at start. Then, clicking any of those links is printing **"Your file was not found"** as Output.

Comment: Routing is possible with any react app, you just need to configure it properly. So, Can you please show us: 1) your react router version. 2) your import for react router and the use of BrowserRouter. 3) have you read and followed the official documentation on [react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) and the basic examples?

Comment: I have updated the question!

Comment: Have a look at the answer and let me know if it helps or if you need further help!

Comment: are you still having this problem? can you post the complete component please?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Routing even possible with create-nw-react-app?

Routing is not dependent on this project's configuration but rather on the use of [React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) library and correct configuration and setting of the library. Basically you can add React-Router to any React project including React Native.

If you use a server to handle the application's requests, for example in a MERN stack, or using a node/express server, you will have to set up some additional settings and configuration (in the server) to handle the routing properly. Since this is not the case, I will continue with the client side case.

**Swap render for component**

Don't use the `render` function from the Route, but rather use the `component` prop to set the component that will be rendered in the Route.

Have a look at [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render).

Use a Route like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

This is the basic use case for a Route and it's the easiest case of routing.

**Switch Routing**

Consider using Switch inside the BrowserRouter if you are going to use multiple Routes.

From [the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch):

> `<Switch>`
>
> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches
>   the location.
>
> How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>`s?
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

So if you have multiple Routes, you can use Switch like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'

class Tool extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                            <Route path="/:user" component={User}/>
                            <Route component={NoMatch}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </React.Fragment>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

**Some tutorials and examples:**

Have a look at these:

- [react-router-v4-complete-guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/)
- [getting-started-with-react-router-v4](https://blog.pusher.com/getting-started-with-react-router-v4/)
- [a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf)
- [the-easiest-tutorial-on-react-router-v4-youll-ever-find](https://itnext.io/the-easiest-tutorial-on-react-router-v4-youll-ever-find-build-a-single-page-application-in-44c453f4123b)

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: the `<React.Fragment>` tags in your example are totally unnecessary