# React Router difference between component with and without function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, containers, connect

```
const PATH = BASE + '/' + id;
<Route path="PATH" render={PageContainer} /> (DOESN'T WORK for the case below)
<Route path="PATH" component={PageContainer} /> (DOESN'T WORK for the case below)
<Route path="PATH" component={ () => <PageContainer /> } /> (WORKS)

Steps:
1) go to the page BASE/1
2) go back to BASE
3) go to BASE/2

PageContainer connects to the store and passes props to Page.
```

Why the second approach works, but the first one not?

```
Update:     <Route path="PATH" render={PageContainer} /> (DOESN'T WORK for the case below)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react router difference between component and render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing it like this:

```
<Route path="PATH" component={PageContainer} />
```

There is a difference between component and render props. You can find the answer here: 
[react router difference between component and render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render)

Comment: <Route path="PATH" component={PageContainer} /> doesn't work
<Route path="PATH" component={() => <PageContainer/>} /> works

Comment: Try accessing like this: <Route path="PATH" component={<PageContainer />} />

Comment: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: I need more context cants say anything from here.

Answer (score 2):

render — A function that returns a React element. It will be called when the path matches. This is similar to component, but is useful for inline rendering and passing extra props to the element.

PageContainer is a component so should called  but not like PageContainer

Change

```
  <Route path="PATH" render={PageContainer} />
```

To

```
  <Route path="PATH" render={<PageContainer />} />
```

In your case I recommend you to use component prop instead of render

```
  <Route path="PATH" component={<PageContainer />} />
```

Comment: <Route path="PATH" component={PageContainer} /> doesn't work <Route path="PATH" component={() => <PageContainer/>} /> works

Comment: @Will Graham As I explained in my answer. Component should be called like <PageContainer/> but not without < />so the following is right syntax <Route path="PATH" component={<PageContainer />}

Comment: I will try, thank you. If it works, I'll accept this answer

Comment: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Connect(StudentSummaryTable) />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.

Comment: component={PageContainer} doesn't work
 component={()=> <PageContainer />} works