# Combing React Router and Redux made my redirection KO

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have to combine use of Redux and React Router.
I tried react Router alone first and when I was clicking my images I was correctly redirected.

I followed [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router) and now when I click my images, I change the address (ex: http://localhost:3000/contact) but nothing displays as if the component was empty.

Root.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactDOM, { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import Users from './users'
import Book from './Book'
import Notfound from './notfound'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './redux/Store/store'

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store = { Store }>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/:filter?" component={App} />
              <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
              <Route path="/book" component={Book} />  
              <Route path='/manual' component={() => { window.location = 'https://------'; return null;} }/>
              <Route path='/contact' component={() => { window.location = 'https://-------'; return null;} }/>
              <Route component={Notfound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
)

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
serviceWorker.unregister();
export default Root
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import myReducer from './redux/Reducers/myReducer'
import Root from './Root'

const store = createStore(myReducer)

render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Link, Redirect, withRouter, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from './images/logo.png';
import book from './images/book.png';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { date } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <img src={logo} />
          <img src={book} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/book')}/>
          <img src={call} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/contact')}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
export default App
```

Do you know what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

When using react router you shouldn't use `window.location` to redirect since this reloads the whole page. The `<Redirect>` component from react-router is a better choice here.

Also you shouldn't use the `component` prop on the `<Route>`-component for things that aren't actually components, as there's the `render` prop for that (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48152635/5228642)).

Furthermore: `<Route exact path="/:filter?" component={App} />` is not going to work since `:filter?` is looking for a variable and `exact` is looking for an *exact* match. Moreover you probably shouldn't put the flexible one first since it's going to match every route that you throw at it. So all the following routes are practically unreachable.

Comment: what do you mean by "you shouldn't use the component prop for things that aren't actually" - I can't locate the problem

Comment: @droledenom I specified the answer. Basically, only use `<Route component>` for actual defined components. For inline render instructions use `<Route render>`. You can find more information in the linked post.