# How to get reactjs router hardcoded params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following route:

```
<Route path="/userstream/:user" component={ Profile } param="stream" />
```

Then in my component i get `:user` in this way: `this.props.match.params.user`

But, how I can get **stream** from hardcoded param?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to pass it as a prop to component:

```
<Route path="/userstream/:user" component={ (props) => <Profile {...props} param="stream" /> }  />
```

Edit: for completeness sake, it's worth to mention a second approach, which is to use a `render` prop:

```
<Route path="/userstream/:user" render={ (props) => <Profile {...props} param="stream" /> }  />
```

There are some performance differences between the two approaches: [react router difference between component and render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render).

Comment: @apokryfos not necessarily.

Comment: Maybe I'm using an older version

Comment: I mean both should work, I just prefer this version, since it's less verbose.

Comment: No I mean I think in older versions of react-router this didn't work. I'm not entirely sure but that's what I remember.

Comment: That must be quite an old version, it's been around for a while. Also it seems there are some performance diffs between the two approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render