# Toggle components in App.js based on routes, works only on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to toggle a few components based on route. I do get it to work on a refresh but not a navigate. Anybody know what I'm missing and doing wrong here?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          pathname: {(this.props.location.pathname)}
          {!this.props.location.pathname.includes('/target') ? <TopBar childProps={childProps} /> : null}
          {!this.props.location.pathname.includes('/target') ? <Header /> : null}
          {this.props.location.pathname.includes('/target') ? <SecondaryHeader /> : null}
            <Routes childProps={childProps} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(App)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a  `non exact`  `Route` for that?

Comment: `<Route path='/target' render={() => <TopBar childProps={childProps} />}`

Comment: @Dupocas You are more than welcome to show me. I'm not a React dev so having a bit of hard time with this here and different approaches. Any help I get is highly highly appreciated.

Comment: Oh. no problems. I'm posting an answer

Comment: @Dupocas thanks, also maybe in short short explain why, how it works and where I should put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a component exported from `react-router-dom` which is called `Route`, and it encapsulates exactly the logic you want.

**Conditionally renders components based on the current `path`**

```
<Router>
    <Route path='/target' render={() => <MyComponent />} />
    <Route exact path='/target' render={() => <AnotherComponent />} />
</Router>
```

- `render` accepts a function which returns some `jsx` (you can also use `component`, see the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render)).
- `path` is the path that `window.location.pathname` must match to render what is being passed to `render` or `component`
- `exact` is whether or not the `path` must be absolute.

Imagine that the current path is `/target/foo`. In this case `MyComponent` will be rendered but `AnotherComponent` won't.

You can also pass a `regex` to `path`, see the full docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md)