# How do i pass the props to another component via react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which displays a list of FM stations. I want to pass the data to individual component because most of the data is already present. However, I am not able to redirect the page to individual FM page upon the click of the button called Click me.

I have used different sources on stackoverflow and other links such as
[react router difference between component and render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render)
https://medium.com/@cristi.nord/props-and-how-to-pass-props-to-components-in-react-part-4-2cc375c17a23

They all point that I am following the docs correctly and now I am not sure how I can resolve this. I understand that I can use the router hooks to resolve this issue, but I am trying to learn why I am not being to resolve it like this.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-morning-tbemq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

React-Router is meant to conditionally render component depending on the url you're in.

To do this you declare the Route like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/some-url">
        <MyComponent />
    </Route>
     <Route path="/some-other-url">
        <MyComponent />
    </Route>
<Switch>
```

You can then either use a `<Link>` to redirect to specific url or do this:

```
const history = useHistory();
const onClick = () => {
    history.push("/some-other-url");
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did know about the useHistory and useLocation hooks but I was trying to achieve it by this way which was incorrect as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick` is returning a `Route` component. Instead, you should have this component already rendered, and either render a [`Redirect` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect), call `history.push`, or simply use a `Link` component.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did know about the useHistory and useLocation hooks but I was trying to achieve it by this way which was incorrect as you pointed out.