# history.push() updates URL in browser but does not renders the appropriate component(Redirect not working too)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router` in my project and using `this.props.history.push()` inside `componentDidMount()` if the user is not looged in ,then redirect him to `Login` component.
This is my code in App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
    }   
    
    componentDidMount(){
        
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
            if(user){
                this.props.dispatch(login(user.email)); 
            }
            else{
                
                this.props.history.push('/login');
            }
        })
    }
        render(){
        //console.log(this.props.isLoggedIn);
        return (<div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={()=><Homepage userName={this.props.username} logout={this.logout}/>} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
        </div>);}
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Below is my index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';

const store= createStore(combineReducers({userState: userState}),applyMiddleware(logger));


ReactDOM.render(
    
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please not that I have removed some unnecessary functions and imports irrelevent to the context of this question.

Now let us come to what I have tried till now:

1. Using `Router` instead of `BrowserRouter` with history object passed to it.
2. Tried removing `switch` but that didn't work too.

I also searched for other questions that address this problem but unfortunately, none of them worked for me.

Please help me to find if there is any issue in my code.

Thank You!!

**EDIT**:

Looks like I'm having a bad day, even `Redirect` isn't working for me!
I'm trying very hard but I don't understand why Login component is not being rendered even when the URL is being changed.

Comment: You aren't using exact path for your Switch's Route. The switch will hit your `/` path first. Try swapping that line with the `/login` line

Comment: Are you using react-router or react-router-dom?

Comment: @Varun I am using react-router-dom with BrowserRouter

Comment: Nothing is working for me! Even if I am using Redurect, even that is not able to render Login component.

Comment: @JontyTyagi I've mimic your code and ran it using exact path for Switch route, it is working as expected. Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ep89cj?file=src/App.js

Comment: I think problem is something else. I tried replacing Login with some other simpler functional component and even that isn't working

Comment: I am using 'react-router-dom' v5.2. Is that something which is causing problem?

Comment: try using render prop instead of component prop for rendering the `<Homepage />`. I have added this in my answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `exact` prop in your Route. Otherwise, `/login` will also match `/` first

```
            <Route exact path="/" component={()=><Homepage userName={this.props.username} logout={this.logout}/>} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Comment: This is now showing cannot read property push of undefined in this.props.history

Comment: Can you paste your entire code to CodeSandbox or StackBlitz, so we could take a look

Comment: hmm... hard to help out in that case. Maybe try using `window.history.push` instead

Comment: I could have given you my entire code, but it is using lots of other files and tools as well. It would be almost impossible to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't use `exact` in your `Route` component. If you don't use `exact` then react will route to `/` path first. It will reads the path(`/login`) as `/` + `login`.
If you provide `exact` to this `/` path then react will route to the specified component which exactly matches the path. It is not necessary to provide an `exact` to all the Route component.

It is necessary when:

For example,

```
<Route exact path="/" component={About} />
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Then you need to provide the exact to parent path.

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
<Route path="/login/profile" component={Profile} />
```

In short, if your next Route component path is a child of the previous path then you need to provide the `exact` property to the parent path.

---

Edited: There is one more thing that I'd like to say that in your Route component of / path you must have a render prop instead of a component prop for rendering the Callback component like this.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={()=><Homepage userName={this.props.username} logout={this.logout}/>} />
```

Some credits to @Sohaib answer. I have added some more explanation to his answer.

Comment: It is saying render is not a function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936972/13847690 this might help with the differences. Read case 3 and case 4 in that answer.

Comment: Thank You everyone guys, for giving your time, but I think I might look for some alternative of react router. No matter what I am doing, it is not working right.