# Issue in using useEffect in a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to use `useEffect` inside a functional component which should only run when the component mounts, but it says that:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem."

**React Code**

[image]

**React Error:**

[image: React Error]

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `render` in your `<Route ... />` into `component`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936972/12101554

`render` doesn't seem to work with React Hooks, but `component` does.

Per [@rishat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287643/rishat) on StackOverflow,

> [Using the render prop] saves you runtime because **no lifecycle methods are run**, ...

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48152635/12101554

The `useEffect()` React Hook is similar to the `React.Component` lifecycle methods (`componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` all in one {plus a few more}), so when you use `render` the Hooks don't work

[The source code of `react-router-dom` also shows us this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/59a4fbc184f3a3cf4c25ee39a7e97f72efed7849/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L112-L116):

```js
if (component)
  return match ? React.createElement(component, props) : null

if (render)
  return match ? render(props) : null
```

As you can see, when you use `render`, you aren't actually calling `React.createElement` so Hooks and lifecycle methods don't work. However, when you use `component`, they do work.

Comment: Really helpful. Many thanks