# Why my Cart.js is not rendering? React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was trying to render my `Carrito.js` component when the user access `/carrito` but the component is not rendering. I tried using `<Link to='/carrito /> Carrito </Link>` and the anchor tag but neither of them renders it.

```
<Router>
        <Route
          path="/tienda"
          exact
          component={({ history }) => <Productos history={history} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/carrito"
          component={({ history }) => <Carrito history={history} />}
        />
</Router>
```

I can give any information if you need anything else

EDIT:

If I render `<Carrito />` where `<Productos />` is, it shows the component, so it could be a problem with the Route

Comment: Just do `<Route
          path="/tienda"
          exact
          component={Productos}
        />`

Comment: ```Productos``` is rendering, what is not rendering is ```Carrito```. It doesn't matter if I render them as you said or as I'm doing, I will eventually use the ```history```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a Code Sandbox. Also, to render with props, you should use [`render` instead of `component`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48152635/11667949)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I just added the `<Switch></Switch>` from `react-router-dom` and inside where the routes and now all rendered.

```
<Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/tienda">
            <Productos />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/carrito">
            <Carrito />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```